# Show/Hide an element programatically in a list of items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was playing around with React and I have a list of elements like this:

```
{posts.map((post) => (
   <div className ="hidden" key={post.key}></div>
   <button onClick = {() => showMore()}>Click to Show</button>
))}
```

posts is a list of json objects. The idea is that only a short description of the post would show and when the button is clicked, it shows the full body.

```
posts = [{
    "title": "Title",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnail": 'images/image.png',
    "body": "",
    "id": 1
}]
```

I want to show that particular post when the button for it is clicked. This is easy to do with document.getElementById but I'm unable to do this with React.

The only way I can think of is a single useState for all the posts but this is not what I want.

This is different from just showing or hiding a single element because in this case I can't just create a single useState. I guess I could create as many useStates as there are posts but I don't really know how this would work.

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information is here -- what's `posts` look like? But probably, you could include `(post, i)` in your arrow function to get the index, then call `showMore(i)`, or something like that. You should have all of the info right there in the `map` callback to uniquely identify the post (maybe `post.key`?). This lets you take whatever action you want specific to a post upon clicking your button.

Comment: I added more detail. My question is what would showMore look like? I just added it there because I assumed that it would involve a function call. I am trying to understand what would be inside that function.

Comment: It depends on what you're doing--if you have a list of posts and whatever you need to show is in that data then you just show/hide based on that, and keep state for each post, perhaps keyed by `post.key` or... If you need to fetch the data then it'd look like a fetch.

Comment: I have a div that is currently hidden which I want to show when the button is clicked. The div contains the post body which is already provided by the json object (I don't need to fetch). I'm not sure how to keep state for each post using map. I'm new to React, is it possible to provide more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this is by creating a Post component which has an internal state:

```js
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
  const handleShowMore = () => setShowMore((prevShowMore) => !prevShowMore);

  return (
    <div class="post" key={post.id}>
      <p>{showMore ? post.description : post.description.substring(0, 10)}</p>
      <button onClick={handleShowMore}>
        Show {showMore ? "Less" : "More"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If `showMore` is false (which it is by default), it will only show the first 10 characters of the string. If it is true, it will show the entire string.

Then in your parent component, I'd map over the posts and render the Post component:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {data.map((post) => (
        <Post post={post} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is a example: https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/KKajvOW

Is this close to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of just creating a Post component!

Comment: My pleasure! Takes a bit of time to get used to React!